# setting up putty to access to my Vbox

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, putty, bitnami

I have a vbox running on my Ubuntu 18.04 Host, but I am having trouble with the networking. I have tried numerous network configurations but I am going in circles. First I tried to use Bridged interface but I read somewhere of issues with  bridged on ubuntu when using wireless. Then I went to NAT for #1 and added Host-Only for #2. I then was told that I needed to port forward port 22 on 127.0.1.1 to 10.0.2.15 which is my Host Only address. Regardless, I still get "no route" when I try to start up Putty. I also noticed that when the appliance boots I get a message in Red "Failed to start Raise Network Interface" scrolling by. I don't know what thus means. I have enabled ssh on the Host. I also have NetworkManager running. What I'd like to do is delete interface #2 and start over.

Comment: Please tell us what is the OS of the guest, it's network configuration, and its SSHD configuration.

Comment: Hi, The guest is running Debian. It is actually a bitnami LAMP appliance. For network on it I have two interfaces #1 is NAT with a few port forwards:  all TCP from 127.0.1.1 ports 888, 22, and 2222 forwarded to 127.0.0.1 port 80,  and 10.0.2.15 , both to port 22. I have cable connected, unchecked. On Interface #2, I have it disabled. For sshd I have it running in both the host (for sure) and the guest (I think). For Putty I am going to 10.0.2.15 port 22. I also have /home/richb201/.ssh/keyfile.ppk set in the SSH,Auth screen.

Comment: On your Debian guest: what is the output of `ip -a`. Also: `systemctl status sshd` and `grep Port /etc/ssh/sshd_config`. This will begin to verify your Debian configuration. Also, I am not sure but I always use `Bridged` adapter for external SSH access or `Host Only` for access from the host only.